# when using eclipse webtools JSDT, the validator doesn't recognise the "get someval() { return this.someVal }" syntax

Tags: javascript, eclipse, ide, jsdt

When using JSDT to edit a javascript source file using this syntax for getter and setter like so;

```
  get action() { return this.aAction },
  set action(action) { this.aAction = action },
```

it fails and returns an error;

> Syntax error on token "get", :
>   expected after this token

here is the full source example;
http://pastebin.com/Xsfnk3b7

any suggestions on a work-around?

Is there some way to define "get" and "set" keywords...?